# iPhone - threads

Tags: iphone

What is the difference between using this

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(doStuff:) 
                       withObject:myObject 
                    waitUntilDone:YES];
```

instead of simply

```
[self doStuff:myObject];
```

in terms of CPU load? Or there are any other advantages?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(doStuff:) 
                   withObject:myObject 
                waitUntilDone:YES];
```

This makes sure that the selector is performed on the main thread by adding it to the main run loop. When you set `waitUntilDone:YES`, you will let your current thread idle as long as the main run loop needs to perform the selector.
In a single threaded environment this will let the runloop run right after you called this, in a multithreaded environment, the main runloop will perform the selector once it does the next step.

You have in any of the both cases a small overhead as the selector isn't performed right after you called the function but at a later point while `[self doStuff:myObject];` performs the selector immediately

Comment: Excuse me guys, but it was not so accurate. If you call that from main thread, the method will be performed immediately because the `waitUntilDone:YES` parameter. The message will skip the run loop and it is important to mention that run loop would never run on this condition because the main run loop will do many stuff including draining autorelease pool and executing queued messages, which could affect memory management and order of execution of the code.

Answer (score 1):

The first one just ensure that your method will be invoked in main thread. If you are not doing multithreading, they should yield same result.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the second message will be sent straight away, while the first is added to the run loop of the main thread so it won't run immediately.